# No output is shown when option 2 is chosen in C++

Tags: c++

So after I enter my input in option 1, then I chose to continue. My input information are gone when choosing the option 2.
I just started my programming course so please give me a lot of advice.
This is the output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG31m.png)

```
struct Human
{
    string name;
    string foods;
    string date;

};

char option;

int main()
{
    do
        {
            int user;
            cout << "You" <<endl;
            cout << "\nChoose one from the menu below" <<endl;
            cout << "1 Enter information" <<endl;
            cout << "2 See information stored" <<endl;
            cout << "\nEnter your option" <<endl;
            cin >> user;
           Human me;
            switch(user)
            {
            case 1:
                {
                    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                    cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
                    getline(cin, me.name, '\n');
                    cout << "Enter your favorite foods: ";
                    getline(cin, me.foods, '\n');
                    cout << "Enter your birthday: ";
                    getline(cin, me.date, '\n');
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                    cout << "Your name is: " << me.name<<endl;
                    cout << "Your favorite foods are: " <<me.foods<<endl;
                    cout << "Your birthday is: " <<me.date<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << "\nDo you wish to continue?" <<endl;
            cout << "Enter 'y' to continue and 'n' to exit" <<endl;
            cout << "Your choice:";
            cin >> option;
        }while(option == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new `Human me;` in every iteration of the do-while loop. When you read input for that `me` in one iteration, the `me` in the next iteration won't know about that.

Read about "scope" and moving the declaration `Human me;` outside of the loop will probably do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Human
{
    string name;
    string foods;
    string date;

};

char option;

int main()
{
    
     Human me;
    do
        {
            int user;
            cout << "You" <<endl;
            cout << "\nChoose one from the menu below" <<endl;
            cout << "1 Enter information" <<endl;
            cout << "2 See information stored" <<endl;
            cout << "\nEnter your option" <<endl;
            cin >> user;
          
            switch(user)
            {
            case 1:
                {
                    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                    cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
                    getline(cin, me.name, '\n');
                    cout << "Enter your favorite foods: ";
                    getline(cin, me.foods, '\n');
                    cout << "Enter your birthday: ";
                    getline(cin, me.date, '\n');
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
                    cout << "Your name is: " << me.name<<endl;
                    cout << "Your favorite foods are: " <<me.foods<<endl;
                    cout << "Your birthday is: " <<me.date<<endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << "\nDo you wish to continue?" <<endl;
            cout << "Enter 'y' to continue and 'n' to exit" <<endl;
            cout << "Your choice:";
            cin >> option;
        }while(option == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

So, Here is The Working Code problem is that you declare struct variable in the loop so every time loop runs it gets again initialized and previous lost
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9y79.png)